# Android Postcodes.io HTTP Request

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

I'm using the AsyncHttpClient class and I can't save the result as a string within the OnSuccess function. Below is an example of the result I want to parse, I am trying to retrieve the "lsoa" value.

```
{
"status" : 200,
"result" : {
    "postcode" : "NW2 1SJ",
    "quality" : 1,
    "eastings" : 524332,
    "northings" : 186558,
    "country" : "England",
    "nhs_ha" : "London",
    "longitude" : -0.207661046004569,
    "latitude" : 51.5642021415348,
    "parliamentary_constituency" : "Finchley and Golders Green",
    "european_electoral_region" : "London",
    "primary_care_trust" : "Barnet",
    "region" : "London",
    "lsoa" : "Barnet 040A",
    "msoa" : "Barnet 040",
    "incode" : "1SJ",
    "outcode" : "NW2",
    "admin_district" : "Barnet",
    "parish" : "Barnet, unparished area",
    "admin_county" : null,
    "admin_ward" : "Childs Hill",
    "ccg" : "NHS Barnet",
    "nuts" : "Barnet",
    "codes" : {
        "admin_district" : "E09000003",
        "admin_county" : "E99999999",
        "admin_ward" : "E05000045",
        "parish" : "E43000193",
        "ccg" : "E38000005",
        "nuts" : "UKI71"
    }
}
```

All I would like to do is store the "lsoa" from the API into a string (s) but I can't even assign the whole output to a string as I get a "*Variable 's' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final*" error.

```
private void queryPostcodes(String searchString){

        String s;
        // Create a client to perform API request
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        mDialog.show();

        // Output the link being checked
        Log.d("Gentrification: ", QUERY_URL + searchString);

        // Have the client get a JSONArray of data and define how to respond
        client.get(QUERY_URL + searchString, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject){
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("X: ", jsonObject.toString());
                s = jsonObject.toString(); //<-- DOESN'T WORK :(
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error){
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage() + " - Postcode not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("X", statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this works? `Log.d("Gentrification: ", jsonObject.toString());` If yes then that will also work.

Comment: anyway, how do you know, that is not working? Where are using the value of `String s`?

Comment: Log.d("Gentrification: ", jsonObject.toString());
The above line works and I can see the output.

I can't compile my app at the moment because of the Variables 's' is access from within inner class error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to press Alt+Enter in AndroidStudio, you'll get a quickfix option: "Transform 's' into one element array'. Click and voila.

The reason of your problem is that `new JsonHttpResponseHandler()` creates new instance of anonymous inner class. Everything you want to access from within should be declared as a field of parent class or a final variable in containing method. On the other hand, you can't make your String final, because final variables get assigned only once. You can create a wrapper class with the single String parameter OR make 's' a field of parent class OR use String[] as a wrapper.

String wrapper option:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Button updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stringBuffer
                        .delete(0, stringBuffer.length())
                        .append(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Field of parent option:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                s = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

String[] option:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] s = new String[1];
        Button updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                s[0] = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        });
    }
}
```